# Missing Header Links. Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, error, luma-theme

[image]

as you can see create an account and login is missing from the frontend

Comment: have you tried redeploying static content?

Comment: didnt work buddy!

Comment: when did it happen? Maybe there's an extension or custom module overriding the default header block.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are some issues in your less file, which are preventing "create an account" and "login" section from appearing to the front end.

Go to **var/log/system.log** and check the log file. You will find all the errors there. Make necessary corrections to your less file accordingly. It should fix your issue.